# Add l1 or l2 regularization to crossentropy() function

Tags: python, theano

The following command is the cross entropy function in [5_convolutional_net.py](https://github.com/Newmu/Theano-Tutorials).
I want to add L1 or L2 regularization to this cost function. I do not know why the `TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'list'` comes up ?

```
def RMSprop(cost, params, lr=0.001, rho=0.9, epsilon=1e-6):
grads = T.grad(cost=cost, wrt=params)
updates = []
for p, g in zip(params, grads):
    acc = theano.shared(p.get_value() * 0.)
    acc_new = rho * acc + (1 - rho) * g ** 2
    gradient_scaling = T.sqrt(acc_new + epsilon)
    g = g / gradient_scaling
    updates.append((acc, acc_new))
    updates.append((p, p - lr * g))
return updates
```

`cost = T.mean(T.nnet.categorical_crossentropy(noise_py_x, Y))
params = [w, w2, w3, w4, w_o]
updates = RMSprop(cost, params, lr=0.001)`

Once used 
`cost+=T.sum(abs(params))`
it gives me `TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'list'`

Answer (score 0):

You can't apply a abs() to a list but to each element of a list:

```
cost+=T.sum([abs(p) for p in params])
```

Comment: `*** AsTensorError: ('Cannot convert [Elemwise{abs_,no_inplace}.0, Elemwise{abs_,no_inplace}.0, Elemwise{abs_,no_inplace}.0, Elemwise{abs_,no_inplace}.0, Elemwise{abs_,no_inplace}.0] to TensorType', <type 'list'>)`